# How to associate foreign keys model in HTML

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am writing portal to manage tasks , i have created following models shown below

and in addition following view shown below , in the HTML(shown below ) i have section i display recent tasks last 30 days,

when i am looping on each main task that can have multiple sub tasks i would like for example to show sub task associated users and details , i know how to get data from main model class data, but i don't know how to retrieve data associated form foreign Key sub model to its main model.

for example how do i display all users for sub task associated to main task

```
task_assign = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="task_assign",default=1)
```

or any other related like all sub tasks descriptions associated to main task for example

```
task_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Please advice

Thanks

### view class

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #filter active runing tasks
        context['active_tasks'] = MainTask.objects.filter(complete=False).count()
        #All oobjects main Task
        context['maintask'] = MainTask.objects.all()

        #All objects Subtask
        context['childtask'] = MainTask.item_main.all()
        #filter task due date
        #due_range = 
        context['due_task'] = MainTask.objects.filter(due_date__day__lte=7, complete=False).count()
        #task paused
        context['task_paused'] = MainTask.objects.filter(task_status='PA', complete=False).count()

        #task paused
        context['task_completed'] = MainTask.objects.filter(task_status='CO', complete=True).count()

        #task paused
        context['task_started'] = MainTask.objects.filter(task_status='NS', complete=True).count()

        ###query for dashboard
        #recent tasks query
        context['recent_task'] = MainTask.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=30), complete=False)

        #Current date time
        now = timezone.now()
        context['current_time'] = now


        return context
```

### model

```
class MainTask(models.Model):
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    global_task_info = models.TextField(max_length=500,default=None) 
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    overall_precent_complete = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    global_task_assign = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="global_task_assign",default=1)
    TASK_STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('ST', 'STARTED'),
    ('NS', 'NOT STARTED'),
    ('IP', 'IN PROGRESS'),
    ('PA', 'PAUSED'),
    ('CO', 'COMPLETED'),
]
    task_status = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=TASK_STATUS_CHOICES,default='NOT STARTED')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title



class ChildTask(models.Model):
    # Relationship Fields
    item_main = models.ForeignKey('ittasks.MainTask',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_main", )
    task_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_info = models.TextField(blank = True)
    task_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sub_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_precent_complete = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    task_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    task_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    task_due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())


    task_assign = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="task_assign",default=1)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_description
```

### html

```
{% if recent_task %}


    {% for rtasks in recent_task %}


         <div class="card m-b-0">
             <div class="card-header" id="heading-{{ rtasks.id }}">
               <h5 class="mb-0">
                 <a class="artasks" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-{{ rtasks.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-{{ rtasks.id }}">
                     <i class="m-r-5 fas fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <span>{{rtasks.task_title}}</span>
                 </a>
               </h5>
             </div>
             <div id="collapse-{{ rtasks.id }}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-{{ rtasks.id }}" data-parent="#accordionExample">
               <div class="card-body">

                                 <span class="todo-desc">{{rtasks.task_title}}</span> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger float-right">{{ current_time|timeuntil:rtasks.created_at }}</span>

                     <ul class="list-inline">
                             <li class="assignee list-inline-item"><img class="rounded-circle" width="40" src="../../assets/images/users/1.jpg" alt="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Steave"></li>
                             <li class="assignee list-inline-item"><img class="rounded-circle" width="40" src="../../assets/images/users/2.jpg" alt="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Jessica"></li>
                             <li class="assignee list-inline-item"><img class="rounded-circle" width="40" src="../../assets/images/users/3.jpg" alt="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Priyanka"></li>
                             <li class="assignee list-inline-item"><img class="rounded-circle" width="40" src="../../assets/images/users/4.jpg" alt="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Selina"></li>
                         </ul>
                 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                 <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center m-t-25">
                         <span>{{rtasks.overall_precent_complete}}% Impressions</span>
                         <div class="ml-auto">
                             <span>{{rtasks.overall_precent_complete}}</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="progress">
                         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 53%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                     </div>
                <div class="comment-footer mt-3">
                         <span class="text-muted float-right">April 14, 2016</span> 
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-cyan btn-sm">View</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Publish</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                     </div>     
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}    
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: The first try that comes in my mind while reading your post is: fetch all child talks that have the main task (In case of one main task) or the *Main Task intance*, then filter all user that have those child talks...

Answer (score 0):

Start in the view with this:

```
your_obj = Your_Model_Class.objects.get(id=1)


context = {
"your_obj" : your_obj,
}
```

then pass your object through the context of the view to the template.

in the template:

```
<p> {{ your_obj.your_model_field }} </p>
```

then in a Foreign key field, it may need to go one layer deeper.

```
<p> {{ your_obj.your_model_field.your_foreign_key_field }} </p>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: basically keep using dot notation to your desired level.